# Codeigniter database update

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter

The table is like this

[image]

and I want to update DecryptionDate by specify ArchiveID and RecipientID

this is my code

```
$this->load->database();
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$data = array('DecryptionDate' => $date);
$array = array('ArchiveID'=>$archiveID.'','RecipientID'=>$userID.'');
$this->db->where($array);
$this->db->update('log', $data);
if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
    echo "SUCCESS";
} else {
    echo "FAIL";
}
```

my problem is I can update the data only when `$archiveID` is 911 and `$userID` is test01 but the program fail to update when `$archiveID` is 911 and `$userID` is test02

after added `echo $this->db->last_query();` I've got

> UPDATE `log` SET `DecryptionDate` = '2011-11-16 20:01:39' WHERE `ArchiveID` = '911' AND `RecipientID` = 'test01'

when ArchiveID is test01 and the update is SUCCESS

and

> UPDATE `log` SET `DecryptionDate` = '2011-11-16 20:03:10' WHERE `ArchiveID` = '911' AND `RecipientID` = 'test02'

when ArchiveID is test02 and the update is FAIL

I've try this

```
$this->load->database();
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$this->db->query('UPDATE log
    SET DecryptionDate = \''.$date.'\'
    WHERE ArchiveID = \''.$archiveID.'\' AND RecipientID = \''.$userID.'\'');
if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
    echo "SUCCESS";
    return TRUE;
} else {
    echo "FAIL";
    return FALSE;
}
```

but the result's still the same

and try check only the RecipientID like this

```
$this->load->database();
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$this->db->query('UPDATE log
    SET DecryptionDate = \''.$date.'\'
    WHERE RecipientID = \''.$userID.'\'');
if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
    echo "SUCCESS";
    return TRUE;
} else {
    echo "FAIL";
    return FALSE;
}
```

make the update success with only record that match with the `RecipientID` but not with duplicate `ArchiveID` with other record

like this

[image]

Finally, I've test update with common php file with following code instead of via CI and also result is fail

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$strSQL = "UPDATE log SET DecryptionDate = '".$date."' WHERE ArchiveID = '911' AND RecipientID = 'test02' ";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
if( mysql_affected_rows($objQuery) != 0 ) 
{ 
    echo (" SUCCESS ");
} else { 

    echo (" FAIL ");
}
```

so I think this must be **database problem**

here is the DB structure
[image]

and ArchiveID and RecipientID are index

[image]

Comment: `$array = array('ArchiveID'=>$archiveID.'','RecipientID'=>$userID.'');` replace this line by `$array = array('ArchiveID'=>$archiveID,'RecipientID'=>$userID);`

Comment: Probably not related to your problem, but is there a reason you write `'ArchiveID'=>$archiveID.'',` instead of just `'ArchiveID'=>$archiveID,` ?

Comment: Thanks, but I've already try `$array = array('ArchiveID'=>$archiveID,'RecipientID'=>$userID);` but the result is still the same

Comment: Have you checked that the test02 entry does not contain any extra whitespace characters? Try `SELECT * FROM log WHERE RecipientID = 'test02';` and see if it contains the second entry of the first figure.

Comment: Yes, I've done that test and it's still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try export the data from database and truncate it then import the data back, it can help, the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine. Please check that all your fields are correctly spelt, and values are as expected.

Try with a more verbose and debugging-friendly way like this, it should help you spot the problem (maybe the `$userID` contains a space, or something trivial like that). Call last_query() at the end to see if the query is really the one you wanted

```
//...
var_dump($archiveID);
var_dump($userID);
$this->db->where('ArchiveID',$archiveID);
$this->db->where('RecipientID',$userID);
$data = array('DecryptionDate' => $date);
$this->db->update('log', $data);

// call this to test the correct query; see if is what you intended
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

Comment: after add `echo $this->db->last_query()` I've got UPDATE `log` SET `DecryptionDate` = '2011-11-16 19:56:16' WHERE `ArchiveID` = '911' AND `RecipientID` = 'test01' which is successful update and UPDATE `log` SET `DecryptionDate` = '2011-11-16 19:59:58' WHERE `ArchiveID` = '911' AND `RecipientID` = 'test02' for fail to update

Comment: That's really strange...If you remove the first where, does this work? (use only where RecipientID = test02, I mean)

Comment: Can you connect to MySQL or PHP MyAdmin and run the "test02" query manually and see if you get a result?

Comment: @DavidHoude No, I can't so this must be database problem?

Comment: @CarryAll did you var_dump() ed 'test02'?

Comment: @CarryAll...and? is it a string with 6 characters as it should be? (I mean the one saved inside the database, not the one you pass to the where condition)

Comment: @DamienPirsy Yes It is `string(3) "911"` and `string(6) "test02"`

Answer (score 0):

When you say no, do you mean no you cannot connect to MySQL or phpMyAdmin, or no, the query on test2 doesn't return any results? If the second one is true, can you do a select * and verify the fields existance? I cant help but think something may have happened to your data.

Comment: I can connect to MySQL the problem is query on test02 is fail and this 's the way I verify field is exist before do the query.
`$this->load->database();
        $this->db->where('ArchiveID', $archid);
        $query = $this->db->get('log');
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $recipient = $row->RecipientID;
            if ((stristr($recipient, $uid) != FALSE) || $recipient == $uid) {
                //echo $recipient;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;`

Answer (score 0):

I have use this code for checking update query status.

```
$this->db->where($array);
$status = $this->db->update('log', $data);
if($status)
   echo 'Success';
else
    echo 'Fail';
```